# ec2 Instance Status Check Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently running a process on an ec2 server that needs to run consistently in the background. I tried to login to the server and I continue to get a Network Error: Connection timed out prompt. When I check the instance, I get the following message:

Instance reachability check failed at February 22, 2020 at 11:15:00 PM UTC-5 (1 days, 13 hours and 34 minutes ago)

To troubleshoot, I have tried rebooting the server but that did not correct the problem. How do I correct this and also prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> An instance status check failure indicates a problem with the
>   instance, such as:

- Failure to boot the operating system
- Failure to mount volumes correctly
- File system issues
- Incompatible drivers
- Kernel panic
- Severe memory pressures

You can check following for troubleshooting
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesStopping.html

> For future reprting and auto recovery you can create a [CloudWatch
>   Alarm](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/automatic-recovery-ec2-cloudwatch/)
>
> For second part

Nothing you can do to stop its occurrence, but for up-time and availability YES you can create another EC2 and add [ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) on the top of both instances which checks the health of instance, so that your users/customers/service might be available during recovery time (from second instance). You can increase number of instances as more as you want for high availability (obviously it involves cost)

Comment: But how do I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Nothing you can do to prevent its occurrence, you can create a cloudwatch alarm to do auto recovery if it occurs

Comment: For user point of view, you can create another EC2 and add ALB on the top of both instances which checks the health of instance, so that your customers might not be affected. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html

Comment: Or even better put the EC2's in an Auto Scaling Group. The ALB does a health check and it fails will no longer route traffic to that EC2, then the ASG will send a Status check and take the unresponding server out of rotation.

Answer (score 4):

I've gone through the same problem

[image]

and then once looking at the EC2 dashboard could see that something wasn't right with it

[image]

but for me rebooting

[image]

and waiting for a 2-3 minutes solved it and then was able to SSH to the instance just fine

[image]

If that becomes a recurrent problem, then I'll follow through with [Jeremy Thompson's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson)

> ... put the EC2's in an Auto Scaling Group. The ALB does a health check and it fails will no longer route traffic to that EC2, then the ASG will send a Status check and take the unresponding server out of rotation.